Cannot update wcf servcie reference in a sdk-converted .csproj project?
In VS2022 I recently converted a .NET Framework 4.8 project file (.csproj) to the new SDK-format (still targeting .NET Framework 4.8). The project contains some WCF service references. Everything still works, no problems so far.
Now one of the referenced services has changed and I therefore need to update the service reference. But the ability to regenerate the code for the service client seems to have gone.
There is no longer a "Configure service references..." option available when right-clicking the service reference in Solution Explorer. And if I bring up Project->Connected Services->Manage Connected Services there are no WCF web service references registered.
What do I do?

You can reference the service like this:
Right-click the project->Add->Service Reference.Finally, enter the URL of your service.


